# Is there any mechanism in WPF to avoid multiple updates of control's state

Tags: wpf, xaml

We have a custom control. Someone can use this control in code and set some properties:

```
<MyControl Property1='value1' Property2='value2'/>
```

When the system read this code it crates instance of MyControl and set properties. On every property changing MyControl performs some calculation. Is there any way to perform calculation only once when control initializing will be completed?

Comment: "when control initializing will be completed". That would be in [OnInitialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.oninitialized.aspx). And there is also a [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event.

Comment: As @Clemens mentioned, it is customary to handle the `UserControl.Loaded` event for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the [`ISupportInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/sk9ex42t.aspx) interface. When the user calls `BeginInit`, just suspend the calculations until `EndInit` is called.

Comment: This works fine in WinForms, but does it works in WPF during XAML reading process?

Comment: @EugeneMaksimov, for XAML I'm not sure, but it will definitely work if the properties are assigned from code, since it's not specific to WPF.